# Most efficient method to represent chessboard

Tags: java, chess

I have a chess program written in Java. Currently I am using a 2d char array to represent the chessboard. Upper case characters to represent white and lower case to represent black. Should I use an array of bytes to reduce the memory usage? Or maybe enums? Thank you.

Comment: There are only 64 cells, there's really _no need_ to care about memory usage. I would create a 2D array of classes, like `ChessBoardCell[][]`

Comment: If you really want to conserve memory, you could store the position of a piece in 2x 3 bits and the piece itself in 4 bits (1 for color, 3 for the piece). That way, you only need a buffer of 32 * 10 = 320 bits or 10 bytes. You can probably find a way to snoop off another bit. But honestly, if you worry about storing a chessboard into 64 chars, you should switch from Java to another language like C or even more low level. But you shouldn't worry about this until it becomes a problem, that is, until you want to store millions or billions of chessboards.

Comment: Thanks for all your comments. My chess program has an undo feature which adds the 2d array to an array list every time a move is made.

Comment: @Alex Shesterov The strength of a chess engine really depends on the execution speed of the move generator. Using classes is the worst mistake you could ever do, as it is way too slow.

Comment: @ xXliolauXx, I totally disagree; the logic of storing and retrieving additional information about a cell could take a lot more time if a fancy way is used to represent cells and additional info (like moves tried, etc.) is stored elsewhere. Besides, if great efficiency matters and it is about CPU ticks, then Java is not the right language anyway.

Comment: @Alex without being rude, have you programmed a chess engine yet? There is no need for any "fancy information" except for the UI, which I agree does need classes. The whole background work however should be done without classes. And I agree that Java isn't the fastest of all languages, but it is fast enough, as long as you don't make mistakes like using classes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In short: The most efficient and professional way is to use Bitboards.

Basically, there are 3 ways of representing a chessboard that are often used:

- 8x8 2-dimensional array:
  Slow but easy to maintain
- 10x12 1-dimensional array:
  Faster, a little bit trickier
- Bitboards:
  They are the fastest method, also used in professional engines like Stockfish or Rybka. Basically, you need a 64-Bit uint for every figure type, where every bit stands for a single field. For more information, i recommend the chessprogramming wiki or google=>bitboards.

Comment: So I have to write all the code for checking legal moves in a single class? No OOP?

Comment: Basically, yes. I would still suggest to make a class or a struct chessboard, to keep the bitboards together cleanly. And try to use static methods and classes wherever possible, it yields another performance gain.

Comment: @xXliolauXx A VERY important detail you overlooked is that the piece-specific bitboard cannot represent which pieces are black vs. white. For that, you need an additional bitboard. Thus the total comes to six bitboards: Pawn, Knight, Bishop, Rook, Queen, and faction. There can ever only be one king for both players so there's no need for an additional bitboard. From there, you can use a byte per player to represent the King's position (1, 64). To save an extra byte you can also put both faction's Kings into a single byte where the lower bits/upper bits represent the two King's positions.

Comment: @Hatefiend I am sorry in advance if I took your comment the wrong way. First of all, why do you consider that a VERY impotant detail? Second, it depends on your definition of figure type wether that already includes color. Third, yes, all your suggestions concerning saving space are correct, but in a chess engine that is not of concern, at all. The advantage of bitboards is not storage space, but the ability to implement the move generator as bit operations, which is the most time consuming part at runtime. Storage is only an issue with lookup tables, but you only store hashes there anyway.